# Asp.net Drop Down List has too many items than the database list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to it all but creating a small Asp.net c# project.

I have a form which pases data to a database table and a quick overview datagrid which re-populates the from should i edit a line on that datagrid. 
I created a seperate Priority DB table/ list to test on a dropdown list on the form, values L,VL,M,H,VH only these added no deletes. I am able to pull the list to the dropdown box and can see all 5 values, however the list is huge and contains another 45 empty items.

If i change ddl_priority.DataTextField = "ID";
the list from top to bottom shows 1 to 45 then 1,2,3,4,5 the later being my values, I tried to restrict the values with "SQL Where" but it didnt work
My code for the drop down list is;

```
public void Populate_priority_dropdownlist()
{
    ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM x_priority_list_tbl", con);
    //ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select [Priority] FROM [x_priority_list_tbl] where [ID] < 7 ", con);
    ad.Fill(ds, "s");
    dt = ds.Tables["s"];
    ddl_priority.DataSource = dt;

    ddl_priority.DataValueField = "Priority";
    ddl_priority.DataTextField = "Priority";
    ddl_priority.DataBind();
}
```

Must be some setting somewhere?

Comment: Can we see your markup as well?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have some table entries with `null` as the value of Priority (or PriorityName ?) column value. Probably you should fix that. You can always add a where condition to your select query so that it will bring up only those records with a valid PriorityName value.

```
ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM x_priority_list_tbl
              WHERE PriorityName is not null and PriorityName<>''", con);
```

Also Set the ID as the `DataValueField` Property value and Set `PriorityName` as the Text Field.

```
ddl_priority.DataValueField = "ID";
ddl_priority.DataTextField = "PriorityName";
```

Assuming your table has columns with name `ID` and `PriorityName` . If your column names are different, you can change it accordingly in the code.